# Office Outlook Add-In resizing taskpane

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, officedev

Is there a way to resize a custom Add-In? I am creating a custom add-in for outlook and would like to make the width bigger. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to resize a task pane?

Comment: Yes, I need to make the width wider.

Comment: Currently we do not support resizing the taskpane's width. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Github Label: “Type: product feature request”
https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions

Answer (score 0):

`OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for resizing a task pane. The [resizeTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo) method of the `window` object doesn't work for task panes from web add-ins.

If you need to be able to resize a custom task pane you may consider creating a VSTO based add-in instead.

Comment: What is this used for? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/requestedwidth

Comment: That is for the initial width of the content add-in. But not for resizing the pane dynamically.